# Laravel website is storing too much of cache or cookies

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, caching

I have Laravel website. When i make changes in laravel file it doesn't get implemented until I remove all the history including cache and cookies.

it seems like website is storing too much of cache or cookies.

But how i can find it and remove it.

Comment: Laravel doesn't cache anything by default, so you probably have a wrong implementation somewhere. Could you show a code example of something that gets cached?

Comment: my url was "/logout" i changed it too "/logoutme" but it was going back again on logout until i remove history. what it could be?

Comment: Are you using a redirect to go to this page?

Comment: yes i am using redirect but not particularly this function

Comment: it is also using Redirect('/') for login and logout

Comment: Please detail more about your question.

Comment: i fount that when i delete Session folder and views folder  inside Storage/faramework/ 
then website work fine

Comment: i think sessions and views are not getting deleted after logout